# Проверка одинаково выбранных значений в разных selectах

Tags: javascript, select, валидация, html-form

Имеется такой интерфейс формы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в данном конкретном примере в каждом select'е выбраны разные значения.

Нужно реализовать функционал проверки на предмет одинаково выбранных значений в разных "частях", как например здесь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

здесь значение "Президиум" выбрано и в Части №1 и в Части №2 - что я является ошибкой в логике формы.

Как такую проверку на одинаково выбранные значения в разных select'ах формы реализовать на JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

Элементарно - получаете выбранные элементы  с обоих селектов и сравниваете, например в момент выбора элемента в любом из селекторов.

```
var select1 = /* document.querySelector... */ ;
var select2 = /* ... */ ;

var selected1 = Array.from(select1).filter(e => e.selected);
var selected2 = Array.from(select2).filter(e => e.selected);

for (let el1 of selected1) {
  for (let el2 of selected2) {
    if (el1.text == el2.text) { /* do some... */ }

    /* или так */

    if (el1.value == el2.value) { /* do some... */ }
  }
}
```